# Website url not move from http to https in opencart v1.5.6?

Tags: opencart

I have added SSL certificate to my website and check Use SSL to 'Yes' then after,I hit my website but its not moving to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **SSL** certificate installed and you do not see the `https://` you can simply force your application from `http://` to `https://` simply by copy/paste the following code in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```